# keyframes not working in Firefox

Tags: html, css

I'm using css animations for my slideshow, but it seems that for some reason it's not working in Firefox (it does on Chrome). Here's my code:

```
#slideshow{ 
    height:20em;
    width:50em;
    animation-name:slide;
    animation-duration:20s;
    animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    -webkit-animation:slide 20s infinite;
}


@-moz-keyframes slide{
    0%   {background : url('1.bmp');}
    50%  {background : url('2.bmp');}
    100% {background : url('1.bmp');}
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide{
    0%   {background : url('1.bmp');}
    50%  {background : url('2.bmp');}
    100% {background : url('1.bmp');}
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Stack Overflow is an English-language site.

Comment: @Shei please post HTML code too

Answer (score 0):

Update: So apparently according to mozilla `background-image` is NOT animatable: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties

It is in Chrome however.

I'll leave the below here because it may be relevant to similar problems.

---

You are referencing a non-prefixed version of your animation in the `#slideshow` block but you don't actually define that animation. Add the following

```
    @keyframes slide{
        0%   {background : url('1.bmp');}
        50%  {background : url('2.bmp');}
        100% {background : url('1.bmp');}
    }
```

You may also want to add the `-moz`(used by Firefox) prefixed version in the `#slideshow` block:

```
    #slideshow{ 
        height:20em;
        width:50em;
        animation-name:slide;
        animation-duration:20s;
        animation-iteration-count:infinite;
        -webkit-animation:slide 20s infinite;

       -moz-animation:slide 20s infinite; /* ADD THIS */
    }
```